# AJAX to Controller Password Confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am newer to both AJAX and MVC and I am trying to make a confirmation interaction.

What I am trying to do is display a box, the user will enter a value and click submit, and then box will AJAX POST (I think that is what I am supposed to use) to the Controller and return a true or false. I cannot seem to figure out how to make this interaction work however.

If I run debug I can see my value getting passed into the Controller, but it ignores my `if` statement to check if the string was correct. Beyond that, I am not sure how to return a true/false and deal with it in my AJAX.

Here is my "best guess" so far.

**AJAX/JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preloadFunc() {
        var prompting = prompt("Please enter your password", "****");

        if (prompting != null && prompting != null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/magicCheck',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'magic': prompting
                },
                success: function () {
                    //let page load
                },
                error: function () {
                    preloadFunc(); //re-ask
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            window.location.replace("google.com"); //Pressing Cancel
        }
    }
    window.onpaint = preloadFunc();
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult magicCheck(string magic)
    {
        bool success = false;
        if (magic == "poof")
        {
            success = true;
        }
        else
        {
            success = false;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

All help greatly appreciated as I am new to this!

Comment: First problem - `window.onpaint = preloadFunc();` should be `window.onpaint = preloadFunc;`. The `onpaint` property expects a reference to a function...you're executing the function immediately and assigning its result (undefined)

Comment: Also, what is `if (prompting != null && prompting != null) {` for? `prompting` will never be `null` - it will always be a string (empty or non-empty)

Comment: You never do anything with the ASP.NET `success` variable, you always redirect to Index.

Comment: @Ian the `!= null` is a simple way to handle "Cancel" being pressed.

Comment: @Austin Can't believe I forgot about that, I'm not sure what I was thinking about. Still, why is the condition there twice?

Comment: @Quentin sooo how do I do some kind of comparison? For the strings.

Comment: @Austin — You're already doing a comparison. You are just using it to set a variable you never use instead of determining your HTTP response with it.

Comment: @Quentin oh..I guess I was just confused because during debug it would always skip the `if`'s during steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all the comments below your post as there are many issues here, but as far as comminication AJAX and returning:

Change the controller to return JSON, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult magicCheck(string magic)
{
    bool success = false;
    if (magic == "poof")
    {
        success = true;
    }
    else
    {
        success = false;
    }
    return Json( new { Success = success });
}
```

Now that the controller is returning JSON you need to change your js to handle it:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/magicCheck',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'magic=' + prompting,   //<-- you didn't need to send JSON for this, you'd have to change your controller if you are going to send a JSON object also... you just need this for now
            success: function (resp) {
                //let page load
                 if ( resp.Success ){
                 // success...
                 }
                 else{
                  //fail
                 }
            },
            error: function () {
                preloadFunc(); //re-ask
            }
        });
```

Comment: A server redirect in an AJAX response will not "undo anything in js after the post"...it will look like a successful response, but the response will contain the redirected page's HTML, which is obviously not desired

Comment: ok, will correct... i've never done a redirect when calling via ajax, but it makes sense what your saying as the handling is done by the programmer.

Comment: Yeah I never do redirects for AJAX responses either (because it makes no sense), I just know the behavior isn't desired. The browser handles the redirect before it returns the response to the JavaScript

Comment: @TMcKeown This worked perfectly! I think I am starting to understand the relationship and role of JSON finally for AJAX.

Comment: Yup, was just waiting for le timer